# Equivariant imbedding of compact manifold

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, equivariant-homotopy

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group smoothly acting on a smooth compact manifold $X$.

**Is it true that there exists a smooth $G$-equivariant imbedding of $X$ into a Euclidean space acted linearly (and smoothly) by $G$?**

I believe that the answer is positive and well known. **I need a reference.**

Comment: This is called Mostow-Palais theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostow%E2%80%93Palais_theorem.